# Vuejs + docker: Cannot use import statement outside a module

Tags: docker, vue.js, ecmascript-6, commonjs

I am running a vuejs app inside docker which works fine on my macOS but does not work on a linux server.

I get the following error:

```
(node:21) Warning: To load an ES module, set "type": "module" in the package.json or use the .mjs extension.
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
/app/node_modules/.bin/vite:2
import { performance } from 'node:perf_hooks'
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
    at internalCompileFunction (node:internal/vm:73:18)
    at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:20)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1205:27)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1295:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1091:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:938:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:83:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47
```

I have type="module" in my html tag as well as "type": "module" in my package.json. Nothing helps.